# Where can I find the Process Control Block (PCB) and GDTR/LDTR contents using GDB and QEMU?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, gdb, qemu

I have a barebone linux kernel with buildroot setup for debugging using QEMU and GDB. I am using the x86_64 architecture.

I want to check how the memory protection works for each process. So basically, I need to find the base and limit values that govern the access to the physical memory.

If I understood correctly, the GDTR register in the x86 architecture "holds the base address (32 bits in protected mode; 64 bits in IA-32e mode) and the 16-bit table limit for the GDT." If not, please let me know where such information is held.

I tried using the `i r` in GDB but the output does not show the GDTR/LDTR contents. I read somewhere that we can use another method while inside the kernel in order to display the results of these registers.

I also need to check the PCB (Process Control Block) contents. I can't seem to find a way to do so. I read somewhere that if we do memory dump in the kernel, we can get the PCB contents, but I can't figure out how to do so.

So, how can I check the contents of PCB and GDTR/LDTR from gdb?

The setup is a simple qemu that launches the linux kernel with buildroot, connects gdb by using `target remote :1234` and execute a simple C program that has fork and exec inside of it.

Comment: You might want to use BOCHS; it's built-in debugger knows about system state like GDTR (and can parse your page tables and so on), while GDB I think doesn't.

Comment: PCB is a generic OS concept, something software implements, not something the CPU itself knows about.  e.g. on Linux, `task_struct` ([Where is PCB on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150734)).  It's part of the guest Linux state so you'd need a Linux kernel debugger, not a full system CPU-state debugger.  (e.g. `kdb` or whatever a more modern alternative is.)